# Program received and didn't handle signal IOT (6), when run Crystal program

Tags: crystal-lang

I have program, that linked to C library "nats"

```
@[Link("nats")]
lib LibNats
  fun natsConnection_ConnectTo(connection: UInt64*, connstr: UInt8*)
  fun natsConnection_PublishString(connection: UInt64*, key: UInt8*, value: UInt8*)
  fun natsConnection_Subscribe(sub: UInt64*, connection: UInt64*, key: UInt8*, cb: (UInt64*, UInt64*, UInt64*) -> Void)
end

connection = uninitialized UInt64
s = uninitialized UInt64

LibNats.natsConnection_ConnectTo(pointerof(connection), "nats://localhost:4222")
LibNats.natsConnection_Subscribe(pointerof(s), pointerof(connection), "qwe", ->(c, s, m) {
  puts m
})
LibNats.natsConnection_PublishString(pointerof(connection), "qwe", "{}")
```

After run it, I receive error: `Program received and didn't handle signal IOT (6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [include file](https://github.com/nats-io/cnats/blob/ba85970f6d0fd4077742013ecde323315487a5c9/src/nats.h#L1900) the first function is:

```
NATS_EXTERN natsStatus
natsConnection_ConnectTo(natsConnection **nc, const char *urls);
```

Look at the double pointer there, whereas in your binding you just use one pointer.

This is very common in C libraries: you have some struct with your data (`natsConnection`) and you usually pass it by reference (hence a pointer) but you receive a pointer to that pointer in a "constructor" function where you want to store that pointer, for which memory is usually allocated by the function itself.

Anyways, the explanation is really long and I don't have time right now, but try with this:

```
@[Link("nats")]
lib LibNats
  type Conn = Void*
  type Sub = Void*

  alias Status = Int32

  fun natsConnection_ConnectTo(connection : Conn*, connstr : UInt8*) : Status
  fun natsConnection_PublishString(connection : Conn, key : UInt8*, value : UInt8*) : Status
  fun natsConnection_Subscribe(sub : Sub*, connection : Conn, key : UInt8*, cb : (UInt64*, UInt64*, UInt64*) -> Void) : Status
end

status = LibNats.natsConnection_ConnectTo(out connection, "nats://localhost:4222")
abort "natsConnection_ConnectTo failed" if status != 0

status = LibNats.natsConnection_Subscribe(out subscription, connection, "qwe", ->(c, s, m) {
  puts m
})
abort "natsConnection_Subscribe failed" if status != 0

status = LibNats.natsConnection_PublishString(connection, "qwe", "{}")
abort "natsConnection_PublishString failed" if status != 0
```

Also read about the [out keyword](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/c_bindings/out.html) and make sure you check for errors.

Comment: How I can avoid exit of program? I want, that process run forever, if it establish nats connection

Comment: Call `sleep` without arguments

Answer (score 0):

For resolving problem, I use explicit pointers `Pointer(UInt64).new(...)` instead `pointerof(...)`:

```
LibNats.natsConnection_ConnectTo(pointerof(connection), "nats://localhost:4222")
LibNats.natsConnection_Subscribe(pointerof(s), Pointer(UInt64).new(connection), "qwe", ->(c, s, m) {
  puts m
})
LibNats.natsConnection_PublishString(Pointer(UInt64).new(connection), "qwe", "{}")
```

Comment: This is 64 bit OS?  Is this a crystal bug?

Comment: 64 bit, don't know about Crystal bug